# Subquery in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subquery

Can you please help with this nested query in pandas :

```
SELECT DISTINCT

mt.*

FROM    Set1 mt INNER JOIN

    (
        SELECT NO_CLIENT, MIN(priority) AS min_priority
        FROM Set1
        GROUP BY NO_CLIENT
        )
        

t  ON   mt.NO_CLIENT = t.NO_CLIENT AND mt.priority = t.min_priority
```

thanks

Comment: You don't need the subquery in pandas, it has built-in ways to get the row with the min/max of a column. See the linked question.